# How can I replace Rhythmbox with Banshee?

Tags: banshee, rhythmbox, default-programs

I have just upgraded to 12.04 and I'm not happy that the integrated music player is once again Rhythmbox. I much prefer Banshee and would prefer to have it as the default music player in the same style as it was before (i.e. Default audio application, completely integrated into sound menu, Ubuntu One integration).

Also, I would like to be rid of Rhythmbox as the default.

Answer (score 16):

### Installing Banshee

To install Banshee, do one of the following, click on this button:

[image: Install via the software center]

or if you want to run in Terminal: `sudo apt-get install banshee`

---

### Uninstalling Rhythmnbox

*This step is optional, however follow if you like.*

Run in Terminal: `sudo apt-get remove rhythmbox`

---

### Making Banshee your Default Media Player

1. Open the application `Details` (You can find it by searching in the Unity dash)
2. Click on `Default Applications`
3. Under `Music`, click the dropdown menu to select `Banshee`
4. Close the application, it saves automatically.

---

### Setting up Ubuntu One integration

You don't need to do anything because `Ubuntu One` uses the `Music` folder in your Home Directory (~/Music) for synchronisation *as far as I know*.

Comment: This is the kind of an answer that a newcomer expects from professionals. Thank you @njallam!

Comment: Ubuntu One does not use the Music folder for synchronization. You can sync your Music folder if you choose, but this does not provide the music store integration that exists in Rhythmbox. The current music store does not work in Banshee.

Comment: Oh, OK.  I'm not too familiar with Ubuntu One, nor the Ubuntu Music Store.  Thank you for that correction.  If you have any ideas please edit that last point for me.